# Fibonacci heap in C

Tags: algorithm, c, priority-queue

(See the [next iteration](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/118443/fibonacci-heap-in-c-follow-up).)

I have rewritten a Fibonacci heap implementation from Java to C.

**fibonacci_heap.h**:

```
#ifndef FIBONACCI_HEAP_H
#define FIBONACCI_HEAP_H

#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#ifdef  __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

    typedef struct fibonacci_heap_t fibonacci_heap_t;

    /***************************************************************************
    * Allocates a new, empty heap with given degree.                           *
    ***************************************************************************/  
    fibonacci_heap_t* fibonacci_heap_t_alloc(size_t initial_capacity,
                                   float load_factor,
                                   size_t (*p_hash_function)(void*),
                                   bool (*p_equals_function)(void*, void*),
                                   int (*p_priority_compare_function)(void*, 
                                                                      void*));

    /***************************************************************************
    * Adds a new element and its priority to the heap only if it is not        *
    * already present.                                                         *
    ***************************************************************************/  
    bool fibonacci_heap_t_add(fibonacci_heap_t* p_heap, 
                              void* p_element, 
                              void* p_priority);

    /***************************************************************************
    * Attempts to assign a higher priority to the element. Return true only    *       
    * if the structure of the heap changed due to this call.                   * 
    ***************************************************************************/  
    bool fibonacci_heap_t_decrease_key(fibonacci_heap_t* p_heap, 
                                       void* p_element, 
                                       void* p_priority);

    /***************************************************************************
    * Return true only if the element is in the heap.                          * 
    ***************************************************************************/  
    bool fibonacci_heap_t_contains_key(fibonacci_heap_t* p_heap, 
                                       void* p_element);

    /***************************************************************************
    * Removes the highest priority element and returns it.                     * 
    ***************************************************************************/  
    void* fibonacci_heap_t_extract_min(fibonacci_heap_t* p_heap);

    /***************************************************************************
    * Returns the highest priority element without removing it.                * 
    ***************************************************************************/  
    void* fibonacci_heap_t_min(fibonacci_heap_t* p_heap);

    /***************************************************************************
    * Returns the size of this heap.                                           * 
    ***************************************************************************/  
    int fibonacci_heap_t_size(fibonacci_heap_t* p_heap);

    /***************************************************************************
    * Drops all the contents of the heap. Only internal structures are         *
    * deallocated; the user is responsible for memory-managing the contents.   * 
    ***************************************************************************/  
    void fibonacci_heap_t_clear(fibonacci_heap_t* p_heap);

    /***************************************************************************
    * Checks that the heap maintains the min-heap property.                    *
    ***************************************************************************/  
    bool fibonacci_heap_t_is_healthy(fibonacci_heap_t* p_heap);

    /***************************************************************************
    * Deallocates the entire heap with its internal structures. The client     *
    * programmer must, however, memory-manage the contents.                    * 
    ***************************************************************************/  
    void fibonacci_heap_t_free(fibonacci_heap_t* p_heap);

#ifdef  __cplusplus
}
#endif

#endif  /* HEAP_H */
```

**fibonacci_heap.c**:

```
#include "fibonacci_heap.h"
#include "unordered_map.h"
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

static const double LOG_PHI = 0.4813;
static const size_t DEFAULT_NODE_ARRAY_CAPACITY = 16;

typedef struct fibonacci_heap_node_t {
    void*                         p_element;
    void*                         p_priority;
    struct fibonacci_heap_node_t* p_parent;
    struct fibonacci_heap_node_t* p_left;
    struct fibonacci_heap_node_t* p_right;
    struct fibonacci_heap_node_t* p_child;
    size_t                        degree;
    bool                          marked;
} fibonacci_heap_node_t;

typedef struct fibonacci_heap_t {
    unordered_map_t*        p_node_map;
    fibonacci_heap_node_t*  p_minimum_node;
    fibonacci_heap_node_t** p_node_array;
    size_t                  node_array_capacity;
    size_t                (*p_hash_function)(void*);
    bool                  (*p_equals_function)(void*, void*);
    int                   (*p_key_compare_function)(void*, void*);
} fibonacci_heap_t;

static fibonacci_heap_node_t* fibonacci_heap_node_t_alloc(void* p_element, 
                                                          void* p_priority) {
    fibonacci_heap_node_t* p_node = malloc(sizeof(fibonacci_heap_node_t));

    if (!p_node) 
    {
        return NULL;
    }

    p_node->p_element  = p_element;
    p_node->p_priority = p_priority;
    p_node->p_parent   = NULL;
    p_node->p_left     = p_node;
    p_node->p_right    = p_node;
    p_node->p_child    = NULL;
    p_node->degree     = 0U;
    p_node->marked     = false;

    return p_node;
}

fibonacci_heap_t* 
fibonacci_heap_t_alloc(size_t map_initial_capacity,
                       float load_factor,
                       size_t (*p_hash_function)(void*),
                       bool (*p_equals_function)(void*, void*),
                       int (*p_key_compare_function)(void*, void*))
{
    fibonacci_heap_t* p_ret;

    if (!p_hash_function)        return NULL;
    if (!p_equals_function)      return NULL;
    if (!p_key_compare_function) return NULL;

    p_ret = malloc(sizeof(fibonacci_heap_t));

    if (!p_ret) return NULL;

    p_ret->p_node_array = malloc(sizeof(fibonacci_heap_node_t*) *
                                 DEFAULT_NODE_ARRAY_CAPACITY);

    if (!p_ret->p_node_array) 
    {
        free(p_ret);
        return NULL;
    }

    p_ret->node_array_capacity = DEFAULT_NODE_ARRAY_CAPACITY;
    p_ret->p_node_map = unordered_map_t_alloc(map_initial_capacity, 
                                              load_factor, 
                                              p_hash_function, 
                                              p_equals_function);

    if (!p_ret->p_node_map)
    {
        free(p_ret->p_node_array);
        free(p_ret);
        return NULL;
    }

    p_ret->p_minimum_node         = NULL;
    p_ret->p_hash_function        = p_hash_function;
    p_ret->p_equals_function      = p_equals_function;
    p_ret->p_key_compare_function = p_key_compare_function;

    return p_ret;
}

bool fibonacci_heap_t_add(fibonacci_heap_t* p_heap, 
                          void* p_element, 
                          void* p_priority) 
{
    fibonacci_heap_node_t* p_node;

    if (!p_heap) return false;
    if (unordered_map_t_contains_key(p_heap->p_node_map, 
                                     p_element))
    {
        /*printf("Element fail: %d\n", p_element);*/
        return false;
    }

    p_node = fibonacci_heap_node_t_alloc(p_element, p_priority);

    if (!p_node) return false;

    if (p_heap->p_minimum_node)
    {
        p_node->p_left = p_heap->p_minimum_node;
        p_node->p_right = p_heap->p_minimum_node->p_right;
        p_heap->p_minimum_node->p_right = p_node;
        p_node->p_right->p_left = p_node;

        if (p_heap->p_key_compare_function(p_priority, 
                                           p_heap->p_minimum_node->p_priority) < 0) 
        {
            p_heap->p_minimum_node = p_node;
        }
    } 
    else p_heap->p_minimum_node = p_node;

    unordered_map_t_put(p_heap->p_node_map, p_element, p_node);
    return true;
}

static void cut(fibonacci_heap_t* p_heap,
                fibonacci_heap_node_t* x, 
                fibonacci_heap_node_t* y)
{
    x->p_left->p_right = x->p_right;
    x->p_right->p_left = x->p_left;
    y->degree--;

    if (y->p_child == x) 
    {
        y->p_child = x->p_right;
    }

    if (y->degree == 0) 
    {
        y->p_child = NULL;
    }

    x->p_left = p_heap->p_minimum_node;
    x->p_right = p_heap->p_minimum_node->p_right;
    p_heap->p_minimum_node->p_right = x;
    x->p_right->p_left = x;

    x->p_parent = NULL;
    x->marked = false;
}

static void cascading_cut(fibonacci_heap_t* p_heap, fibonacci_heap_node_t* y)
{
    fibonacci_heap_node_t* z = y->p_parent;

    if (z)
    {
        if (y->marked)
        {
            cut(p_heap, y, z);
            cascading_cut(p_heap, z);
        }
        else 
        {
            y->marked = true;
        }
    }
}

bool fibonacci_heap_t_decrease_key(fibonacci_heap_t* p_heap, 
                                   void* p_element, 
                                   void* p_priority)
{
    fibonacci_heap_node_t* x;
    fibonacci_heap_node_t* y;

    if (!p_heap) return false;

    x = unordered_map_t_get(p_heap->p_node_map, p_element);

    if (!x) return false;

    if (p_heap->p_key_compare_function(x->p_priority, p_priority) <= 0)
    {
        /* Cannot improve priority of the input element. */
        return false;
    }

    x->p_priority = p_priority;
    y = x->p_parent;

    if (y && p_heap->p_key_compare_function(x->p_priority, y->p_priority) < 0) 
    {
        cut(p_heap, x, y);
        cascading_cut(p_heap, y);
    }

    if (p_heap->p_key_compare_function(x->p_priority, p_heap->p_minimum_node->p_priority) < 0)
    {
        p_heap->p_minimum_node = x;
    }

    return true;
}

static bool check_array(fibonacci_heap_t* p_heap, size_t size)
{
    if (p_heap->node_array_capacity < size) 
    {
        free(p_heap->p_node_array);
        p_heap->p_node_array = malloc(sizeof(fibonacci_heap_t*) * size);

        if (!p_heap->p_node_array) 
        {
            return false;
        }

        p_heap->node_array_capacity = size;
        return true;
    } 
    else 
    {
        return true;
    }
}

static void link(fibonacci_heap_node_t* y, fibonacci_heap_node_t* x)
{
    y->p_left->p_right = y->p_right;
    y->p_right->p_left = y->p_left;

    y->p_parent = x;

    if (!x->p_child)
    {
        x->p_child = y;
        y->p_right = y;
        y->p_left = y;
    }
    else
    {
        y->p_left = x->p_child;
        y->p_right = x->p_child->p_right;
        x->p_child->p_right = y;
        y->p_right->p_left = y;
    }

    x->degree++;
    y->marked = false;
}

static void consolidate(fibonacci_heap_t* p_heap)
{
    size_t array_size = 
            (size_t)(floor
                      (log
                        (unordered_map_t_size(p_heap->p_node_map)) 
                      / LOG_PHI)) + 1;
    size_t number_of_roots;
    size_t degree;
    size_t i;
    fibonacci_heap_node_t* x;
    fibonacci_heap_node_t* y;
    fibonacci_heap_node_t* tmp;
    fibonacci_heap_node_t* next;

    check_array(p_heap, array_size);

    /* Set the internal node array components to NULL. */
    memset(p_heap->p_node_array, 
           0, 
           array_size * sizeof(fibonacci_heap_node_t*));

    number_of_roots = 0;
    x = p_heap->p_minimum_node;

    if (x) 
    {
        ++number_of_roots;
        x = x->p_right;

        while (x != p_heap->p_minimum_node)
        {
            ++number_of_roots;
            x = x->p_right;
        }
    }

    while (number_of_roots > 0) 
    {
        degree = x->degree;
        next = x->p_right;

        while(true)
        {
            y = p_heap->p_node_array[degree];

            if (!y) break;

            if (p_heap->p_key_compare_function(x->p_priority, 
                                               y->p_priority) > 0) 
            {
                tmp = y;
                y = x;
                x = tmp;
            }

            link(y, x);
            p_heap->p_node_array[degree] = NULL;
            ++degree;
        }

        p_heap->p_node_array[degree] = x;
        x = next;
        --number_of_roots;
    }

    p_heap->p_minimum_node = NULL;

    for (i = 0; i < array_size; ++i) 
    {
        y = p_heap->p_node_array[i];

        if (!y) continue;

        if (p_heap->p_minimum_node) 
        {
            y->p_left->p_right = y->p_right;
            y->p_right->p_left = y->p_left;

            y->p_left = p_heap->p_minimum_node;
            y->p_right = p_heap->p_minimum_node->p_right;
            p_heap->p_minimum_node->p_right = y;
            y->p_right->p_left = y;

            if (p_heap->p_key_compare_function(
                   y->p_priority, 
                   p_heap->p_minimum_node->p_priority) < 0)
            {
                p_heap->p_minimum_node = y;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            p_heap->p_minimum_node = y;
        }
    }
}

void* fibonacci_heap_t_extract_min(fibonacci_heap_t* p_heap)
{
    fibonacci_heap_node_t* z;
    fibonacci_heap_node_t* x;
    fibonacci_heap_node_t* tmp_right;
    fibonacci_heap_node_t* node_to_free;

    void* p_ret;
    size_t number_of_children;

    if (!p_heap) return NULL;

    z = p_heap->p_minimum_node;

    if (!z) return NULL; /* Heap is empty. */

    number_of_children = z->degree;
    x = z->p_child;

    while (number_of_children > 0) 
    {
        tmp_right = x->p_right;

        x->p_left->p_right = x->p_right;
        x->p_right->p_left = x->p_left;

        x->p_left = p_heap->p_minimum_node;
        x->p_right = p_heap->p_minimum_node->p_right;
        p_heap->p_minimum_node->p_right = x;
        x->p_right->p_left = x;

        x->p_parent = NULL;
        x = tmp_right;
        --number_of_children;
    }

    z->p_left->p_right = z->p_right;
    z->p_right->p_left = z->p_left;

    p_ret = p_heap->p_minimum_node->p_element;

    if (z == z->p_right)
    {
        node_to_free = p_heap->p_minimum_node;
        p_heap->p_minimum_node = NULL;
    }
    else 
    {
        node_to_free = p_heap->p_minimum_node;
        p_heap->p_minimum_node = z->p_right;
//        puts("Before consolidate");
        consolidate(p_heap);
//        puts("After  consolidate");
    }

    unordered_map_t_remove(p_heap->p_node_map, p_ret);
    free(node_to_free);
    return p_ret;
}

void fibonacci_heap_t_free(fibonacci_heap_t* p_heap)
{
    if (!p_heap) 
    {
        return;
    }

    if (p_heap->p_node_array) 
    {
        free(p_heap->p_node_array);
    }

    if (p_heap->p_node_map)
    {
        unordered_map_t_free(p_heap->p_node_map);
    }

    free(p_heap);
}



bool fibonacci_heap_t_contains_key(fibonacci_heap_t* p_heap, void* p_element)
{
    if (!p_heap) return false;

    return unordered_map_t_contains_key(p_heap->p_node_map, p_element);
}

void* fibonacci_heap_t_min(fibonacci_heap_t* p_heap)
{
    if (!p_heap)                return NULL;
    if (p_heap->p_minimum_node) return p_heap->p_minimum_node->p_element;

    return NULL;
}

int fibonacci_heap_t_size(fibonacci_heap_t* p_heap)
{
    if (!p_heap) return 0;
    return unordered_map_t_size(p_heap->p_node_map);
}

static void clear_nodes_impl(fibonacci_heap_node_t* node)
{
    fibonacci_heap_node_t* current;
    fibonacci_heap_node_t* next_sibling;

    if (!node->p_child) 
    {
        free(node);
        return;
    }

    current = node->p_child;

    while (true) 
    {
        next_sibling = current->p_right;
        clear_nodes_impl(current);
        current = next_sibling;

        if (current == node->p_child)
        {
            free(node);
            return;
        }
    }
}

void fibonacci_heap_t_clear(fibonacci_heap_t* p_heap)
{
    fibonacci_heap_node_t* current;

    if (!p_heap) return;
    if (!p_heap->p_minimum_node) return;

    current = p_heap->p_minimum_node;

    while (true)
    {
        clear_nodes_impl(current);
        current = current->p_right;

        if (current == p_heap->p_minimum_node) break;
    }

    unordered_map_t_clear(p_heap->p_node_map);
}

static bool tree_is_healthy(fibonacci_heap_t* p_heap,
                            fibonacci_heap_node_t* node)
{
    fibonacci_heap_node_t* begin;

    if (!node)          return true;

    begin = node;

    while (true) 
    {
        if (p_heap->p_key_compare_function(node->p_priority, 
                                           node->p_parent->p_priority) < 0) 
        {
            return false;
        }

        if (!tree_is_healthy(p_heap, node)) return false;

        begin = begin->p_right;

        if (begin == node) return false;
    }

    return true;
}

static bool check_root_list(fibonacci_heap_t* p_heap)
{
    fibonacci_heap_node_t* current = p_heap->p_minimum_node;

    while (true)
    {
        if (p_heap->
                p_key_compare_function(current->p_priority,
                                       p_heap->p_minimum_node->p_priority) < 0) 
        {
            return false;
        }

        current = current->p_right;

        if (current == p_heap->p_minimum_node) return true;
    }
}

bool fibonacci_heap_t_is_healthy(fibonacci_heap_t* p_heap)
{
    fibonacci_heap_node_t* root;

    if (!p_heap) return false;
    if (!p_heap->p_minimum_node) return true;

    /* Check that in the root list, 'minimum_node' points to the node
       with largest priority. 
     */
    if (!check_root_list(p_heap)) return false;

    root = p_heap->p_minimum_node;

    /* Check that all trees are min-heap ordered: the priority of any child is
     * not higher than the priority of its parent. */
    while (root)
    {
        if (!tree_is_healthy(p_heap, root->p_child))
        {
            return false;
        }

        root = root->p_right;

        if (root == p_heap->p_minimum_node) return true;
    }
}
```

(You can find everything necessary for demonstration [here](https://github.com/coderodde/coderodde.c.utils).)

Since I have no prior experience of writing C code in a professional setting, I came up with this list of questions:

1. I heard that `_t` prefix is reserved for data types in POSIX; how should I go about making it clear that an identifier is a type name?
2. Is it OK to prepend pointer variables with `p_`?
3. (**Not errors!**) Compilation (**clang**) gives me a long list of related warnings. The program "works", yet I would like to get rid of them.
4. What is the best way of using curly braces?
5. Should I use "shortcut" variables? For instance, `my_list` instead of `data->db->...->list`.
6. Can you spot any chance of memory leaks?
7. Please tell me anything that comes to mind.

Comment: the end of function: `fibonacci_heap_t_is_healthy()`  contains a extra closing brace '}'

Comment: the declaration of the typedef's within the `fibonacci_heap.c` file is in conflict with the typedef within the `fibonacci_heap.h` file.  strongly suggest: 1) remove the current `typedef` from the header file 2) move the `typedef`s from the source file to the header file

Comment: the function: `fibonacci_heap_t_is_healthy()` needs the statement: `return false;` inserted before the final closing brace '}'

Comment: if your compiling with the `-Wconversion` parameter, then this line: `size_t array_size =
        (size_t)(floor (log
                        (unordered_map_t_size(p_heap->p_node_map) )
                      / LOG_PHI)) + 1;` will raise a warning.  suggest changing to: `size_t array_size =
        (size_t)(floor (log
                        ((double)unordered_map_t_size(p_heap->p_node_map) )
                      / LOG_PHI)) + 1;`

Answer (score 5):

In regards to your questions:

1. I see no real benefit of suffixing `struct` types with `_t` - it just adds clutter.
2. As well prefixing every pointer with `p_` introduces a lot of clutter and makes the code harder to read since now all identifiers start with the same prefix - this typically means your brain has to do a lot more work and read a lot more characters before it can identify the actual variable name.
3. Errm, well then fix them :). Turn on "Treat Warnings As Errors" (in clang it's the `-Werror` flag) - this provides a good incentive to fix them.
4. The best way is to use them consistently. So this:

   > ```
   > } 
   > else p_heap->p_minimum_node = p_node;
   > ```

   should be this (since that is your default bracing style):

   ```
   }
   else
   {
       p_heap->p_minimum_node = p_node;
   }
   ```
5. It's ok to use a local variable to store the value of some lengthy de-referencing sequence if it's used more than once in the scope. Although something like `data->db->...->list` would be a bit of a code smell indicating that your abstractions are not quite right.
6. Glancing over the code it seems ok. But if you want to be sure: Write unit tests and use a tool like valgrind to check for memory leaks. Some unit test frameworks like [Cpputest](http://cpputest.github.io/) have build-in memory checking which can be handy.
7. See below.

---

A few other things:

1. Since `fibonacci_heap_node_t` is local to just the implementation file, it could be shortened to `heap_node` - this will make a few lines somewhat shorter.
2. As mentioned in a comment: You already have a `typedef` for `fibonacci_heap_t` in your header - don't put one in your implementation.
3. In `fibonacci_heap_t_alloc` the variable to hold the return value is badly named as `p_ret` - it's returning the heap so the best way to name it is `heap`.
4. `fibonacci_heap_t_add` returns `false` in a whole range of scenarios.

   1. Programmer error (the passed in heap pointer is `NULL`)
   2. Failed to allocate memory
   3. The element already exists in the heap (this may be perfectly fine)

   The first two are probably fatal and only the 3rd one is a possibly expected situation. You may want to consider to implement your own error codes along the lines of [`errno`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/errno.3.html), [`perror`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/perror.3.html) and [`strerror`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strerror.3.html). Change your methods to return error codes where sensible (i.e. on the public interface methods).
5. `check_array` seems to a very bad name for a method which resizes an array to a specific size. Also you may want to consider [`realloc`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/malloc.3.html).
6. In `fibonacci_heap_t_min` I would change the logic around to deal with the `NULL` cases first and use the standard case as the main return line like this:

   ```
   void* fibonacci_heap_t_min(fibonacci_heap_t* p_heap)
   {
       if (!p_heap)                 return NULL;
       if (!p_heap->p_minimum_node) return NULL;

       return p_heap->p_minimum_node->p_element;
   }
   ```

Comment: Due to possible memory fragmentation, if `realloc` fails, there is however chance that `malloc/calloc` will succeed?

Comment: @coderodde: Not really, `realloc` will try [to allocate a new block if the current one cannot be expanded](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25435175/220986). It will automatically copy the memory if that's the case.