# YAGOP - Yet Another Generic Object Pool

Tags: performance, c, memory-management, c99

While thinking about [this question](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/118443/fibonacci-heap-in-c-follow-up) it struck me that one problem of linked data structures always seems to be loss of memory locality and performance could possibly be improved if all allocated nodes are in a contiguous block of memory. So hacked together an object pool implementation in C.

The code compiles with `gcc -std=c99 -pedantic -Wall -Werror -O3` without any warnings.

Things I'd like to draw review attention to:

- Standard conformance
- Portability
- Performance improvements
- C best practices

All other reviews are welcome as well of course.

**Header**

```
#ifndef OBJECT_POOL_H
#define OBJECT_POOL_H

#include <stddef.h>

/*
 * This is an implementation of a generic pre-allocated object pool with automatic growth. It pre-allocates
 * storage for a number of objects of a defined size (a single object pool can only hold objects which are
 * all of the same size). If the pool runs out of storage it will double its capacity automatically but adding
 * an additional buffer with double the capacity of the previous buffer. It will try smaller capacity increases
 * if the doubling fails.
 * By default a maximum of OBJECT_POOL_MAX_NUM_BUFFERS will be created yielding at most 31 doubling steps (first
 * buffer will hold initial_capacity items).
 * So the default number of items it can hold at most is initial_capacity * (2^33 - 1)
 * The pre-allocated objects are padded to the next multiple of 4 bytes.
 */

/*
 * Maximum number of buffers. #define yourself if you want something different
 */
#ifndef OBJECT_POOL_MAX_NUM_BUFFERS
#define OBJECT_POOL_MAX_NUM_BUFFERS 32
#endif /* OBJECT_POOL_MAX_NUM_BUFFERS */

/*
 * Default initial capacity. #define yourself if you want something different
 */
#ifndef OBJECT_POOL_DEFAULT_INITIAL_CAPACITY
#define OBJECT_POOL_DEFAULT_INITIAL_CAPACITY 64
#endif /* OBJECT_POOL_DEFAULT_INITIAL_CAPACITY */

/*
 * Type to represent an object_pool object.
 */
typedef struct _object_pool object_pool;

/*
 * Creates an new object_pool object. item_size will be rounded up to the nearest
 * multiple of 4.
 * Returns a pointer to the created object pool object.
 * Returns NULL under when at least one of the following conditions are detected:
 *  - item_size is 0
 *  - initial_capacity is 0
 *  - failure to allocate memory for the pool
 */
object_pool *object_pool_create(size_t item_size, size_t initial_capacity);

/*
 * Initializes an object_pool object with capacity of OBJECT_POOL_DEFAULT_INITIAL_CAPACITY items. Otherwise see above.
 */
object_pool *object_pool_create_default(size_t item_size);

/*
 * Obtains a pointer to an item from the object pool. This may result the object pool in increasing it's capacity.
 * Previously obtained pointers via object_pool_get will remain valid when the pool grows. The initialization state
 * of the object pointed to by the pointer is not defined (e.g. it may contain random data). The caller of this method
 * is required to properly initialize the object before using it.
 *
 * Returns NULL if it failed to obtain an item which can be caused by:
 *  - pool is NULL
 *  - failed to grow the pool due to memory exhaustion
 *  - maximum number of buffers has been allocated and they are all depleted
 */
void *object_pool_get(object_pool *pool);

/*
 * Returns an item back to the object pool so it can be used again.
 * Returns true if the item was put back into the pool and false otherwise.
 *
 * Specifically false will be returned when at least one of the following conditions are detected:
 *  - pool is NULL
 *  - item is NULL
 *  - item does not point to an object held within the internal buffers
 */
bool object_pool_put(object_pool *pool, void *item);

/*
 * Releases all memory associated with the object pool. Accessing objects through pointers obtained via object_pool_get
 * after this method has been called will invoke undefined behaviour (e.g. most likely will crash but that's not guaranteed)!
 * It is safe to call this on a NULL pointer (in which case this is a noop)
 */
void object_pool_free(object_pool *pool);

#endif /* OBJECT_POOL_H */
```

**Implementation**

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stddef.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#include "object_pool.h"

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
/// STACK structure, for internal use - used to manage use and free lists
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

typedef struct _stack
{
    char **items;
    size_t top;
    size_t size;
} stack;

static bool stack_init(stack *s, size_t size)
{
    if (!s)
    {
        return false;
    }

    s->items = malloc(size * sizeof(*s->items));
    if (!s->items)
    {
        return false;
    }

    s->top = 0;
    s->size = size;

    return true;
}

static void stack_destroy(stack *s)
{
    if (s)
    {
        free(s->items);
    }
}

static bool stack_isfull(stack *s)
{
    return s && (s->top == s->size);
}

static bool stack_isempty(stack *s)
{
    return s && (s->top == 0);
}

static bool stack_push(stack *s, char *item)
{
    if (!s || stack_isfull(s))
    {
        return false;
    }
    s->items[s->top] = item;
    s->top += 1;
    return true;
}

static char *stack_pop(stack *s)
{
    if (!s || stack_isempty(s))
    {
        return NULL;
    }
    s->top -= 1;
    return s->items[s->top];
}


///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
/// BUFFER structure, for internal use - represents a single object buffer
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

typedef struct _buffer
{
    char *buffer;
    char *virgin_element;
    char * const last_element;
    stack reuse_list;
    stack inuse_list;
    const size_t capacity;
    const size_t item_size;
} buffer;

static bool buffer_init(buffer *buf, size_t item_size, size_t capacity, size_t *actual_capacity)
{
    if (!buf)
    {
        return false;
    }

    char *b = NULL;
    do
    {
        // in case memory allocation fails, we try smaller sizes until minimum size
        b = malloc(item_size * capacity);
    } while (!b && (capacity >>= 2) > OBJECT_POOL_DEFAULT_INITIAL_CAPACITY);

    if (!b)
    {
        return false;
    }

    buffer local_init = 
    { 
        .buffer = b, 
        .virgin_element = b, 
        .last_element = b + (capacity - 1) * item_size,
        .reuse_list = { 0 },
        .inuse_list = { 0 },
        .capacity = capacity,
        .item_size = item_size 
    };
    memcpy(buf, &local_init, sizeof(local_init));

    *actual_capacity = capacity;

    if (!stack_init(&buf->reuse_list, capacity))
    {
        free(buf->buffer);
        return false;
    }

    if (!stack_init(&buf->inuse_list, capacity))
    {
        stack_destroy(&buf->reuse_list);
        free(buf->buffer);
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}

static void buffer_destroy(buffer *buf)
{
    if (buf)
    {
        stack_destroy(&buf->reuse_list);
        stack_destroy(&buf->inuse_list);
        free(buf->buffer);
    }
}

static bool buffer_isempty(buffer *buf)
{
    // if the inuse list is full then all items have been handed out so the buffer is considered empty
    return buf && stack_isfull(&buf->inuse_list);
}

static void *buffer_get_item(buffer *buf)
{
    if (!buf || buffer_isempty(buf))
    {
        return NULL;
    }

    char *item = stack_pop(&buf->reuse_list);
    if (!item)
    {
        // no item for re-use available > get a fresh one
        item = buf->virgin_element;
        buf->virgin_element += buf->item_size;
    }

    return stack_push(&buf->inuse_list, item) ? item : NULL;
}

static bool buffer_put_item(buffer *buf, void *item)
{
    char *ptr = item;
    if (ptr >= buf->buffer && ptr <= buf->last_element)
    {
        return stack_push(&buf->reuse_list, item);
    }
    return false;
}

////////////////////////////
/// The actual object pool
////////////////////////////

struct _object_pool
{
    buffer buffers[OBJECT_POOL_MAX_NUM_BUFFERS];
    size_t num_buffers;
    size_t last_buffer_size;
    size_t item_size;
};

object_pool *object_pool_create(size_t item_size, size_t initial_capacity)
{
    if (!item_size || !initial_capacity)
    {
        return NULL;
    }

    object_pool *pool = calloc(1, sizeof(*pool));
    if (!pool)
    {
        return NULL;
    }

    // round up to next multiple of 4
    item_size = ((item_size + 3) / 4) * 4;

    size_t actual_capacity;
    if (!buffer_init(&pool->buffers[0], item_size, initial_capacity, &actual_capacity))
    {
        free(pool);
        return NULL;
    }

    pool->item_size = item_size;
    pool->num_buffers = 1;
    pool->last_buffer_size = actual_capacity;

    return pool;
}

object_pool *object_pool_create_default(size_t item_size)
{
    return object_pool_create(item_size, OBJECT_POOL_DEFAULT_INITIAL_CAPACITY);
}

void *object_pool_get(object_pool *pool)
{
    if (!pool)
    {
        return NULL;
    }

    // find a buffer which still has some items left to hand out
    buffer *buf = NULL;
    for (int i = 0; i < pool->num_buffers; ++i)
    {
        if (!buffer_isempty(&pool->buffers[i]))
        {
            buf = &pool->buffers[i];
            break;
        }
    }

    // all buffers are depleted -> need to create a new one
    if (!buf)
    {
        if (pool->num_buffers == OBJECT_POOL_MAX_NUM_BUFFERS)
        {
            // too bad, no space left
            return NULL;
        }

        buf = &pool->buffers[pool->num_buffers];
        size_t actual_capacity;
        if (!buffer_init(buf, pool->item_size, pool->last_buffer_size * 2, &actual_capacity))
        {
            return NULL;
        }
        pool->num_buffers += 1;
        pool->last_buffer_size = actual_capacity;
    }

    return buffer_get_item(buf);
}

bool object_pool_put(object_pool *pool, void *item)
{
    if (!pool || !item)
    {
        return false;
    }

    // find the buffer the item belongs to
    for (int i = 0; i < pool->num_buffers; ++i)
    {
        if (buffer_put_item(&pool->buffers[i], item))
        {
            return true;
        }
    }

    return false;
}

void object_pool_free(object_pool *pool)
{
    if (!pool)
    {
        return;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < pool->num_buffers; ++i)
    {
        buffer_destroy(&pool->buffers[i]);
    }

    free(pool);
}
```

**Test**

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stddef.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>

#include "object_pool.h"

typedef struct _test_t
{
    int val;
    bool pad1;
    bool pad2;
    bool pad3;
    bool really;
} test_t;

#define ASSERT(x, msg) do { if (!(x)) { printf("%s\n", msg); exit(-1); } } while(0)

static void test_object_pool_returns_null_with_invalid_parameters()
{
    ASSERT(!object_pool_create(0, 1), "unexpected object returned");
    ASSERT(!object_pool_create(1, 0), "unexpected object returned");
    ASSERT(!object_pool_create(0, 0), "unexpected object returned");
    ASSERT(!object_pool_create_default(0), "unexpected object returned");
}

static void test_object_pool_free_null_doesnt_crash()
{
    object_pool_free(NULL);
}

static void test_object_pool_invalid_put_doesnt_crash()
{
    test_t t;
    object_pool *pool = object_pool_create(sizeof(test_t), 1);
    ASSERT(pool, "init failed");
    ASSERT(!object_pool_put(pool, &t), "invalid item put succeeded");
    ASSERT(!object_pool_put(pool, NULL), "invalid NULL put succeeded");
    object_pool_free(pool);
}

static void test_object_pool_get_and_put()
{
    object_pool *pool = object_pool_create(sizeof(test_t), 1);
    ASSERT(pool, "init failed");

    const int num_items = 1000;
    test_t **objects = malloc(sizeof(test_t *) * num_items);

    for (int i = 0; i < num_items; ++i)
    {
        test_t *o = object_pool_get(pool);
        ASSERT(o, "failed to get object");
        o->val = i;
        o->really = true;
        objects[i] = o;
    }
    for (int j = 0; j < num_items; ++j)
    {
        ASSERT(objects[j]->really, "not really?");
        ASSERT(objects[j]->val == j, "value failed");
        ASSERT(object_pool_put(pool, objects[j]), "failed to put");
    }

    free(objects);
    object_pool_free(pool);
}

static void test_object_pool_performance(bool with_free)
{
    int num_iterations = with_free ? 10000 : 1;
    int num_items = with_free ? 10000 : 100000000;
    unsigned long long total = num_iterations * num_items;

    test_t **items = calloc(num_items, sizeof(test_t *));

    object_pool *pool = object_pool_create(sizeof(test_t), num_items);
    ASSERT(pool, "init failed");

    clock_t start, end;
    double elapsed;

    start = clock();
    for (int i = 0; i < num_iterations; ++i)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < num_items; ++j)
        {
            items[j] = malloc(sizeof(test_t));
            items[j]->really = true;
        }
        if (with_free)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < num_items; ++j)
            {
                free(items[j]);
            }
        }
    }
    end = clock();
    elapsed = (end - start) / (double)CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
    printf("malloc%s of %llu items took %f sec (%u items/sec)\n", with_free ? " and free" : "", total, elapsed, (unsigned int)(total / elapsed));

    if (!with_free)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < num_items; ++j)
        {
            free(items[j]);
        }
    }

    start = clock();
    for (int i = 0; i < num_iterations; ++i)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < num_items; ++j)
        {
            items[j] = object_pool_get(pool);
            items[j]->really = true;
        }
        if (with_free)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < num_items; ++j)
            {
                object_pool_put(pool, items[j]);
            }
        }
    }
    end = clock();
    elapsed = (end - start) / (double)CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
    printf("get%s of %llu items took %f sec (%u items/sec)\n", with_free ? " and put" : "", total, elapsed, (unsigned int)(total / elapsed));
    free(items);
    object_pool_free(pool);
}


int main(void)
{
    test_object_pool_returns_null_with_invalid_parameters();
    test_object_pool_free_null_doesnt_crash();
    test_object_pool_invalid_put_doesnt_crash();
    test_object_pool_get_and_put();

    test_object_pool_performance(false);
    test_object_pool_performance(true);
}
```

**Test Output**

Compiled with `gcc -std=c99 -Wall -Werror -pedantic -O3` and gcc 4.9.2 on cygwin 2.5.0

```
malloc of 100000000 items took 7.875000 sec (12698412 items/sec)
get of 100000000 items took 0.984000 sec (101626016 items/sec)
malloc and free of 100000000 items took 13.938000 sec (7174630 items/sec)
get and put of 100000000 items took 2.750000 sec (36363636 items/sec)
```

clang 3.5.1 on the same platform and same build options yields almost identical results.

---

**Update:** With the `inuse_list` replaced with an `inuse_counter` the performance improves somewhat:

```
malloc of 100000000 items took 7.797000 sec (12825445 items/sec)
get of 100000000 items took 0.547000 sec (182815356 items/sec)
malloc and free of 100000000 items took 13.906000 sec (7191140 items/sec)
get and put of 100000000 items took 0.594000 sec (168350168 items/sec)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Inuse stack purpose?

I'm not sure what purpose your `inuse` stack serves.  If you create a pool of 100 items, and then call `get()` followed by `put()`, you will have put one item on the `inuse` stack which also appears on the `reuse` stack.  If you do this again, you will put the same item on the `inuse` stack a second time (a duplicate).  Repeat 100 times and the `inuse` stack will become full and you won't be able to allocate any more items, even though there are actually all 100 items left to allocate.

The `inuse` stack should be replaced by a simple counter of how many items are in use.  You can increment the counter on each `get` and decrement it on each `put`.

Comment: Good point, I missed that. I guess I need to add a check to make sure the object pool is a big as I expect it to be (the tests all pass since the object pool will simply expand). Also I agree that an inuse counter would suffice.